# Acessing Azure DML History

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to see all the DML history of a table (or the entire database) when using Azure SQL Databases?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can.

You can view Query Performance either through the Azure Portal or by using The Dynamic Management Views.

Within the Azure Portal click "Manage" > "Administration" > "Query Performance". Refer to screenshot: [image: here]
This is NO SQL Profiler but, SQL Profiler runs a trace, which is not supported in WASD.

The Azure Portal doesn't show you "profiler" data, it shows you a dump from the query cache.

You can also use the Dynamic Management Views to diagnose performance problems. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx